# Why are my motors attached to an Arduino MEGA not running?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, adafruit, hardware

[image][image][image][image][image]I verified my code and uploaded it to the board and that was successful.

Info: 
  - Using Mega 2560 Arduino Board with Adafruit V1 
  - 3 DC 12 volt motors 
  - on HP computer

Here is my code:

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor(1, MOTOR12_8KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_8KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor3(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ);

void setup()  {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Motor Test!");
  motor.setSpeed(20); //set speed of motor
  motor2.setSpeed(20); //set speed of motor
  motor3.setSpeed(25); //set speed of motor     
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tack"); //first song starts 
  motor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(14000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //first song ends
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(13000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //second song starts 
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(24000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //second song ends 
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(17000);

   Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //third song starts 
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(23000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //third song ends 
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(21000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(3000);

  Serial.print("tack"); //fourth song starts 
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //fourth song ends
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(21000);
   //waving motor
  Serial.print("tick"); 
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  //Waving motor
  Serial.print("tick"); //first song starts
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

   Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //first song ends
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(14000);

  Serial.print("tick"); 
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tack"); //SEcond song starts
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

   Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //second song ends
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(15000);


  Serial.print("tick"); 
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tack"); //Third song starts
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

   Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //third song ends
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(14000);

  Serial.print("tick"); //fourth song starts
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

   Serial.print("tock");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick");
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tack"); 
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(2000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //fourth song ends
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  delay(7000);

  //dancing motor
  Serial.print("tock"); //first song starts
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(11000);

  Serial.print("tick"); 
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  delay(22000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //first song stops //second song starts
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(16000);

    Serial.print("tick"); //Second song stops
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  delay(28000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //Third song starts
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(15000);

  Serial.print("tick"); //Third song stops
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  delay(33000);

  Serial.print("tock"); //fourth song starts
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(16000);

  Serial.print("tick"); 
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tick"); //fourth song ends
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  delay(16000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not trying to drive the motors directly from the output pins ...

Answer (score 4):

As you did not give details I assume the following:

- You supply the MEGA via USB or external 5-12V power supply
- the motors are supplied via an extra external 12V power supply with sufficiant amperage
- All cabeling is checked and correct

Looks like this schematic (without 12V power supply attached to the motor shield)
[image: AF_motor_shield_v1]
[image: AF_Motor_shield_v2]

To your code:

- Get rid of the delay()s - they block processing so what happens:

  ```
   motor.run(FORWARD);  // => You give a command via lib
   delay(2000); // You stop your processing so the motor is not running
  ```

so you have two options both need the definition of a timeStamp var

- working with a (blocking) while loops
- or creating a finite state machine (search here on SO for details)

So I will for simplicity use the first approach

```
 // Copy this var before your setup
 unsigned long timeStamp = 0;
// use your complete setup 
 void setup(){...}
 // Change your loop functions like thes first three converted lines 
 void loop(){
  timeStamp = millis();
  Serial.print("tick");
  while(millis()-timeStamp < 2000){     
     motor.run(FORWARD);
  }   
  timeStamp = millis();   // resets the time to current
  Serial.print("tock");
  while(millis()-timeStamp < 5000){     
     motor.run(RELEASE);
  }
  timeStamp = millis();   // resets the time to current
  Serial.print("tack"); //first song starts 
  while(millis()-timeStamp < 2000){   
     motor.run(BACKWARD);
  }
// .... AND SO ON .....
}
```

Be aware that the whiles are blocking but for your sequential processing its ok.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106646/discussion-on-answer-by-codebreaker007-why-are-my-motors-attached-to-an-arduino).

Comment: Codebreaker, you are more patient than I.